# using GetText to translate wordpress using variables instead of default language

Tags: wordpress, gettext

I want to make my wordpress theme translation ready.

I was thinking to use GetText function within wordpress like: `_e('sometext')`

But I was thinking, what happens when I want to change default English 'sometext', I have to go to different php files (where I used `_e('sometext')`) find all instances and replace it with `_e('sometext2')` ?

Or in my PO file I just make English column, use `_e('sometext')` in wp php files, but in PO file specify 'sometext2'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use something similar to the concept of constants, e.g:

```
<?php _e('TXT_ABOUT_INTO'); ?>
```

TXT_ABOUT_INTO will be like a placeholder, and you will need to create a translation file for English as well as for other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you decided to replace "sometext" with "some other text" you would need to go through the templates wherever _e('sometext') appeared and replace it with _e('some other text').

But... imagine you did not wrap your text in gettext calls. Then you would have to go through your templates to replace "sometext" with "some other text".

Not a lot of difference, and if you were to do a global find & replace you'd be much less likely to accidently change something if your search term was "_e('sometext')" than "sometext".

I've followed your example, but you should be including the text domain when you wrap the text, e.g. _e('sometext', 'my-theme')